# CustomScrollView within ExpansionTile error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Tried to fix this reading some documentation and some open issues but was not lucky.. Could someone please help?

I am getting this error:

> type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast

Not sure why though I tried adding container wrapping the component, adding height, adding flexible box etc...

No lucky

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleData {
  SampleData(this.title, [this.children = const <SizedBox>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<SizedBox> children;
}

final List<SampleData> data = <SampleData>[
  SampleData("IT", [
        SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              new SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Text('fesfefes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
  ]),
];

class Branch extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test 123'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: 500,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Item(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item(this.sample);

  final SampleData sample;

  Widget _buildTiles(SampleData root) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 500,
      child: ExpansionTile(
        key: PageStorageKey<SampleData>(root),
        title: Text(root.title),
        children: root.children,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(sample);
  }
}
`
```

Comment: It would be super great if you only can specify what line of code brings you such an error

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code blow 
You can remove

```
//key: PageStorageKey<SampleData>(root),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleData {
  SampleData(this.title, [this.children = const <SizedBox>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<SizedBox> children;
}

final List<SampleData> data = <SampleData>[
  SampleData("IT", [
    SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          new SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text('fesfefes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ]),
];

class Branch extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test 123'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: 500,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Item(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item(this.sample);

  final SampleData sample;

  Widget _buildTiles(SampleData root) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 500,
      child: ExpansionTile(
        //key: PageStorageKey<SampleData>(root),
        title: Text(root.title),
        children: root.children,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(sample);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Branch(),
    );
  }
}
```